# Get form value from Sonata Admin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, sonata-admin

I would like get value from form of Sonata Admin, but in source html i have for example:

```
<input type="text" class="span5" maxlength="255" required="required" name="s215268450cfc7[username]" id="s215268450cfc7_username">
```

**s215268450cfc7** this is uniqid, but for what this is add to all fields in form? This is regenerate after refresh page.

I would like get value from this form, but i can't use:

```
$('#s215268450cfc7_username').val()
```

because this is still renames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse `uniqId` from the `<form>` element, or you can use:

```
$('form [id$="_username"]').val()
```

Also, from Twig template, you can access name something like this (depending on whether you have access to the whole form, or only to the username field):

```
{{ form.children.username.vars.name }}
```